# How to search Gmail conversations that do not have certain people replied

Tags: gmail, search

I need to find open conversations sent to help@company.com that do not have received a reply from csr@company.com yet.

```
to:help@company.com -"csr@company.com"
```

queries like the above fetches everything as it searches the first email in every conversation (which would not obviously have any traces of csr@company.com) and then returns the entire conversation in the search result, which is not the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a three step solution.

Step 1: Search all conversations that received a reply from csr@company.com using the below search query

```
to:help@company.com from:csr@company.com
```

Step 2: Label all the search results as "replied" using the gmail UI

Step 3: Search for conversations that are NOT labelled as "replied"

```
to:help@company.com -label:replied
```

I got the desired results :)